# Stripping source from linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is there a (/an efficient) way of stripping unwanted source from the linux kernel? Would it be possible for the configurators (xconfig, menuconfig) to work?

As an example, I'm planning to create a different VFS design, which might break all the VFS-dependent kernel components. Also, working with the full kernel source (currently ~400 MB) is not desirable due to space reasons (I'm only interested in booting the system & debugging my code).

Note: I've thought about removing files, but I can't find how to remove the dependencies on them.

[edit] Note 2: Ok, I'll try again deciphering the Kbuild system.

Comment: You may have a little bit of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on. If you're changing a component, a) you have to make sure components that depend on it are still working correctly and b) removing other components present at compile or runtime has absolutely no effect on your changes.

Comment: I want a kernel with a minimum of features on which I can experiment.

Comment: @user2969477 You mentioned menuconfig.  Have you tried using it to modify your .config file to remove whole subsystems?  Don't mess with removing actual source files.

Comment: @PeterL. That won't fit my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the files just hanging there (which unless your hard disk is 50MB, it's usually not a problem), you can disable basically every disableable feature by configuring the kernel using it's own configuration tools.

For example, simply type

```
$ make menuconfig    # or any other available configuration option
```

and start by saying no to everything you don't need. There's a LOT of stuff, so this may take some time! Read the README of the kernel. There's another option (which I don't remember the name) that starts the configuration with the minimum configuration automatically detected from your running kernel. That may make things easier.

Comment: > There's another option (which I don't remember the name) that starts the configuration with the minimum configuration : `make localmodconfig`

Comment: Do this. Reconfiguration is well supported, and easy to do. If you remove some code you'll run into trouble if you ever want to rebase, or merge against another linux tree.